# What is the name of classification of water, air and soil?

Tags: ecology

The definition of living organisms is all types of organisms are capable of some degree of response to stimuli, reproduction, growth, development and homeostasis.
Non-living organisms are inanimate and have stopped displaying capabilities for growth, reproduction, respiration, metabolism and movement. So what do you call air, water, and soil.
plus I am writing an assignment about environment protection. So  I am talking about how certain chemical affects the air, water(sea, and river) and soil.
So how do I classify this three thing, making them be very specific, other than non-living things, as this group is too broad.

Comment: Air, water, and the non-living components of soil, along with rock, sand, etc. are all part of the environment. They don't have a specific class or name. Of course, living organisms are part of the environment or ecosystem as well. I don't understand what your question is asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ecology, non-living components can be grouped under the term **abiotic factors** or **abiotic components**. This includes water, air, light, soil, temperature, and many other qualities that describe the organism's surroundings. These are in contrast to biotic factors, which can include predators, prey, and competitors.

[Abiotic Component- Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abiotic_component)

Answer (score 0):

Gas, liquid & solid are three classes in to which the majority of the matter - as generally understood - in air, water & soil would be included in.

Gases, liquids, and solids are only 3 of a multitude of possible states of matter. They are the 3 states that we are most familiar with in normal life. Air, water and soil are not broad categories of non-living matter, but is each just a mixture of matter (unless you mean pure water). 
If by air you mean the gas mixture of our environment then it is a particular mixture of gases including nitrogen, oxygen, carbon dioxide, and others - or if you mean "the air outside" then it would include solids like small particles of, say, leaf debris or car-tyre rubber.

The matter that makes up living and non-living things is exactly the same and is categorised by chemists and particle physicists.
Living things are unique in the way that matter is caught up in a self-reproducing and entropy-offsetting complex system, which have evolved in to the elaborate systems of the living cell.

If by non-living organisms you mean "dead organisms" which once lived, then these can be thought of as the matter which was left when the dynamic process of life that animated the matter ceased or moved on. Simplistically, life is analogous to an eddy (or 'whirlpool') in a stream of water. Water molecules enter and exit the eddy, just like atoms enter and exit our bodies. If the currents change and the eddy disappears, the water where the eddy was still remains.
Of course the stream carries the water away quickly, rather than it sitting there as a dead organism for some time as the ecosystem recycles its matter.